# API written in C# using nancyfx running on WampServer

Tags: c#, html, web, wamp, nancy

I am still relatively new to writing API's and web services, so bear with me if I use incorrect terminology.

I want to know if it is possible to create an API in C# using nancyfx (or any other framework) or even just a simple web app and then set it up as a continually running web service using WampServer. I'm pretty new to Wamp, all I have done so far is create a few rudimentary pages with php; but I can't seem to find any information about running a web service with Wamp using a different back end language other than php.

Answer (score 2):

WAMP is stand for **W**indows **A**pache **M**ySQL **P**HP. As I can say, you can't run a C# web service with it base configuration. However, you actually don't need this. If you are on .net Core, there is a [Kestrel web server](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer). You can use it to serve your app. On a .net framework you have a [HttpListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx) which can help you to implement self-hosted web service (for example, a windows service which hosts your application).

There are many other options, btw. Try google for some kind of "Hosting .net web application" or "Self-hosted .net web application"